# What should I do to get the Outmatched: 2 Insane AI achievement?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

What should I do to get the **Outmatched: 2 Insane AI** achievement?

I've watched like dozen of online tutorials, where is shown how to do that. The only problem is that those `cannon`/`spine` rushes worked only in older versions. With the newest version (**1.1.2.16755**) nothing works, since insane AI uses *map-hack* (they don't scout at all) and attack your hidden `pylon` (which they haven't seen/scouted) right when you start warping it in.

And I don't think it is possible to beat 2 insane AI with regular (non-rush) gameplay, as they will soon attack with such a giant army that nothing can stop it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blizzard recently added a new custom map which makes it pretty easy to do this using the map Burning Tide.

A full guide to beating the insane AI on this map can be found on YouTube (also read the description).

This method worked for me in patch 1.1.1 - I'm not sure if it's still working but you should give it a try ;)

Comment: I would just like to note that it is easy to get the [1v4 against Very Hard AI Achievement the same way](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/5325935/worlds_easiest_way_to_get_sc2_outmatched_achievements_patch/).

Comment: Why opponent doesn't attack on the map? On the goal to win is just to collect more minerals then your opponents in a limited time frame?

Answer (score 3):

I did 1v7AI FFA and 1v4 Hard by setting all the AI to Zerg and going Terran on Lava Flow.  Right at the beginning, fly over to one of the island expansions and mass Cattlebruisers.  Burn excess minerals on turrets.